# Applying Realm plugin in Kotlin project results in compilation error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, realm, kotlin

I'm trying to add Realm to an Android project, I've added the project level `classpath` dependency, but putting the
`apply plugin: 'realm-android'`
line in my module's `build.gradle` file results in the following build error:

`Error:Execution failed for task ':data:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac'.
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/jetbrains/kotlin/annotation/AnnotationProcessorWrapper`

Without that line, the application builds and runs fine, there is no Realm code in it yet.

Project level build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.6'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.3.0"
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'

        test {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/test/kotlin']
        }
    }
}

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.6'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

dependencies {  
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(path: ':domain')

    compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.6'

    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxkotlin:0.60.0'

    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.6.3'
    testCompile 'com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Can you include your entire gradle build script, both for the app module and the project.

Comment: Update: someone suggested downgrading to 2.2.2 which instantly fixed it, so apparently it's some obscure issue with the 2.3.0 release.

Comment: I also added the Gradle files, in case someone can spot the mistake in them.

Comment: This is the pull request that altered kapt-based projects although I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work... https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/4022

Comment: Adding `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` to `app/build.gradle` solves this? This issue is tracked by https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4087

Comment: That does indeed solve it, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To close this question:
The comment @zaki50 wrote worked for me which is:

Adding `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` to app/build.gradle. 
I added it right after `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'`.

This issue is tracked by https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4087